# как преобразовать данные которые приходят от magoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Использую данный код, но вот данные не преобразуются не пойму почему

```
Order.find()
    .then(orders => {
        orders = orders.map((order) => {
            if (order.status === 0){
                order.status = 'Новый';
            }
            order.time = moment(order.time).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
            console.log(order);
            return order;
        });
        res.render('user', {
            username: req.user.username,
            title: 'Главная страница',
            order: orders
        });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Получаю вот такие данные, на только один объект выведу

```
{
    _id: 5a0bdde700a4c7168416e8ef,
    orderId: 16,
    description: 'Тест',
    number: 10,
    information: '',
    file: 'Скриншот 2017-08-21 14.48.41.png',
    name: 'Василий',
    phone: '79503164233',
    email: '',
    juid: null,
    prepayment: null,
    time: 2017-11-21T21:00:00.000Z,
    prioity: 0,
    __v: 0,
    action: true,
    createdAt: 2017-11-15T06:25:18.636Z,
    status: 0 
}
```

Но получаю также в этом формате 2017-11-21T21:00:00.000Z

Comment: Может у вас order.status - строка?

Comment: `console.log(order);` выводит значение с новыми полями или старыми?

Comment: Грубо говоря я вот пример на jsfind сделал https://jsfiddle.net/rusline/gxzngwx6/3/ Там выходят ошибки. Что-то типо этого выводит

Comment: @Руслан нет, в fiddle ошибки, потому что вы некорректно сформировали объект в нём. В [таком варианте](https://jsfiddle.net/gxzngwx6/7/) ошибок нет

Comment: @Regent А если у меня из mongoose такие данные приходят, как я должен дату сделать в кавычках? как понимаю из-за этого у меня проблемы с преобразованием?

Comment: @Regent или как-то по другому можно преобразовывать данные?

Comment: Код преобразования написан правильно и должен отрабатывать. Покажие, что у вас на входе, и какой массив получается на выходе (consoel.dir(orders) до orders.map и после (по паре элементов оставьте!))

Comment: @Руслан вы посмотрите какого типа данные у вас в `time`. Вполне возможно, что там передаётся, например, `Date`, а не `string`. Да и вообще в вопросе не помешал бы [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а иначе это всё гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: @Regent console.log(typeof order.time); То получаю object. А в мангусе этот тип данных ISODate("2017-11-22T09:00:00.0Z")

Comment: @АлексейМатвеев вот что получаю https://jsfiddle.net/rusline/gxzngwx6/8/ Тут все не уместилось как Вы просили сделать console.dir

Comment: Мне дали наводку Mongoose возвращает свои объекты, которые менять нельзя

Comment: @Руслан И поменяйте тему вопроса! Сейчас заголовок не соответствует вопросу!

Comment: @АлексейМатвеев На какой, как преобразовать данные которые приходят от magoose. Что-то типо этого чтобы соответствовала тема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose возвращает свои объекты, которые менять нельзя.
Если хочется простые объекты, то нужно

```
Order.find().lean().then ...
```